Maximum circle in Altium
I want to draw big circle with radius = 1329mm. But cannot work in altium. And what the maximum size of circle in altium?

I'm curious about the application for a Ø2.6 m large PCB!

I just placed a 2.8m radius circle in AD16. It definitely doesn't behave well when dragging it around, but that may or may not be a problem. What exact problem are you having?

@TimWilliams I just want to test to get the maximum radius for circle in altium. Its mean impossible to draw until that radius. Thanks for opinion.

It looks like there is something weird going on at about 2540mm (specifically 2539.75mm). Here is an attempt to define a 2.6m x 2.6m PCB outline (moving the origin into the square does not help):
As commented below, that's almost exactly a 100" x 100" PCB.

I guess this puts the kibosh on my plans to have a full-size canoe manufactured by PCBway or JLC PCB. Sad, the RGB LEDs would have been awesome.
So, in conclusion, there's apparently no limit on an arc or circle radius provided the control points are within the 100" x 100" hidden working area.

I think the max coordinates in PCB space is 1000000 mils (give or take a few zeros there). It should round off nicely to some petty large multiple of 254 - 2m54 is plausible

Moving the origin doesn't help because there is an absolute coordinate system "behind the curtains"

Ah, yes - https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/indicate-visual-cues-at-the-coordinate-limit-of-pcb-design-space-beyond-which-objects-should-not-be-placed. || 100000mil it is

@MrGerber You beat me to it. The absolute coordinate system pokes its head up from time to time,.

Another mention of it here: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/laying-out-your-pcb?version=18.0 "up to 100x100 inches"

This base unit in mils - and in float, for some strange reason - creates all kinds of silly conversion/rounding issues for people designing in metric. There is a rather old feature request to change the coordinate system into integer base in nm because of this

(cracks knuckles) Alright... Time to place down SMTs. This will only take six months...

Heck, using uint64, the base unit could be Å, and you could still draw a circuit board with a diameter 1.3x larger than the sun.
